# ImproperlyConfigured at /api/customereport/

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

i am getting this error, which was not there previously , having trouble to rectify help needed in this

```
class MeterSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):  
    url = serializers.HyperlinkedIdentityField(view_name="meter_reading:meters-list")
    customer_reports = CustomerReportSerializer(source='customerreport_set', many=True,read_only=True) 
    class Meta:
        model = Meter
        fields = ['number','customer_reports','customer','url']



class CustomerReportSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    meter_no = serializers.SerializerMethodField(method_name='meter_num')
    customer_name = serializers.SerializerMethodField(method_name='cust_name')
    customer_number = serializers.SerializerMethodField(method_name='cust_number')
    class Meta:
        model = CustomerReport
        fields = ('meter_no','meter','customer_name','date','customer_unit','unit_rate','bill_amount','consumer_number','customer_number','pending_units',)
```

*routers.py*

```
router.register('customer', CustomerViewSet)
router.register('meters',MeterViewSet,basename='meters')
router.register('issues',IssueViewSet)
router.register('customereport',CustomerReportViewSet,basename='customerreport')
# router.register('users',UserViewset)

urlpatterns = router.urls
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)),
    path('api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework')),
    path('meter_access/', MeterAccess.as_view(),name='meter_access'),
]
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting ?

Comment: Can you include the code for `CustomerReportViewSet`?